# how to add my css file to prestashop header

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

im new in prestashop . 
i create my css file and want to add it to prestashop theme.
how can i add the new fill and make prestashop read the file in the header section ? 
in furoms i see that thy said to add it to hookheader , i tried to add it to some moudle and do the fallow:

1) add to the theme header file `{hook h="myCssHook"}`

2) add to some rendom module function:

```
 public function myCsshook(&params)
   {
      $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'prestashop/myshop/theme/css/myoverride/myCsstheme.css', 'all');
   }
```

3) in the module installition copy and add:

```
  || $this->registerHook('myCssHook') == false
```

and its didnt work . 
im using prestashop 1.6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In your Install method

```
!$this->registerHook('header')
```

And add this method, you should place your css file in your module folder under views/css

public function hookHeader($params){

```
  $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'views/css/myCssTheme.css', 'all');
```

}